# Непонятка с полем mysql

Tags: mysql

В таблице users_sessions, есть поле hash **int(35)**. Почему-то когда пытаюсь добавить в него к примеру более 10 цифр, то оно генерирует непонятное число **2147483647**.

```
INSERT INTO `test`.`users_sessions` (`id`, `uid`, `key`, `value`, `hash`, `time`) VALUES (NULL, '12', 'key', 'value', '11111111111', '1234567890');
```

Текст ошибки:

```
1 row(s) inserted.
Inserted row id: 3
Warning: #1264 Out of range value for column 'hash' at row 1
```

Comment: это "непонятное число" - 256^4/2

Comment: Вы выходите за пределы INT'а. 
Вопрос #1: Почему у вас хэши состоят только из цифр?
Вопрос #2: Вы эти хэши сортируете? Если нет - задайте VARCHAR

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ограничения int от -2147483647 до +2147483647